# How to find what is causing "Invalid Refresh Token" on Identity Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, identityserver4, refresh-token

I hope someone can help me here..

We use Identity Server 4 to manage the client authentications. We have some recent issues where clients are facing the following error..

```
Refresh token validation failed. aborting, {
"ClientId": "3xx",
"ClientName": "xx",
"GrantType": "refresh_token",
"Raw": {
"client_id": "xx",
"grant_type": "refresh_token",
"refresh_token": "***REDACTED***",
"scope": "xx",
"client_assertion_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
"client_assertion": "***REDACTED***"
}
}
```

I have checked the **dbo.PersistedGrants** table in the Identity server DB (We use default Identity server SQL DB) and I can see the refresh token grants are there for the same user and Clients. The user consents are also active and never revoked for these clients. Clients have also confirmed the consents are active on their end. Also the refresh tokens are not expired yet.

So I have 2 questions...

1. What else could cause Refresh token expired if the above said is in
   place?
2. How can we get more debug or detailed info under the hood to find out which factor is causing the failure

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If the [RefreshTokenUsage](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/client/) client configuration is set to OneTime use (the default), if the client sends the same refresh token twice, the user will be logged out.

Perhaps this is the cause of your trouble?

See the documentation for the setting [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/client/)

Comment: Thanks Tore.. In our Clients Table for all clients the value for RefreshTokenExpiration & RefreshTokenUsage is set to 1. With the fact that only some refresh tokens are erroring out I think we can take the setting out of the question ?

Comment: Also the [Key] field in **dbo.PersistedGrants** table is not the actual Refresh Token I guess as this seems to be some sort of encrypted key for that refresh token ?

Comment: Ok I have confirmed from the client that they use latest refresh token that is issued along with the token response. What else could be failing and any extended logs we can get from IDS?

Comment: Set the log level to debug/trace in IdentityServer and in the client and try to see what error you get that cause the signout.   its not a race-condition that two independent services or handlers sends/uses the refresh token at the same time?

Comment: Do look at the traffic using a tool like https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler and explore the requests around the point of failure

Comment: Thanks Tore.. Logs are now turned on and we are monitoring . Will update here if we get any concrete info.